# Source R scripts in different folders

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a question about sourcing R scripts in different folders. Suppose I created a new project in R Studio. The project folder contains several folders (data, different folders containing the scripots, latex folder, plot folder etc). Is there a way to automatically source all R scripts within this project folder?    Thanks

Comment: So not just within the `R/` directory, you mean?

Comment: @DavidRobinson exactly not just in folder. There are contained in different subfolders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this function for sourcing all R files in a specific folder.

```
## finds all .R and .r files within a folder and sources them
sourceFolder <- function(folder, recursive = FALSE, ...) 
{ 
    files <- list.files(folder, pattern = "[.][rR]$", 
                        full.names = TRUE, recursive = recursive)
    if (!length(files))
        stop(simpleError(sprintf('No R files in folder "%s"', folder)))
    src <- invisible(lapply(files, source, ...))
    message(sprintf('%s files sourced from folder "%s"', length(src), folder))
}
```

So, if I have a folder on my desktop named `Rfiles` I can source all the files with a `.r` or `.R` extension with the call

```
sourceFolder("./Desktop/Rfiles")
# 6 files sourced from folder "./Desktop/Rfiles"
```

You could use the `recursive` argument to source all the R files in the subdirectories

```
sourceFolder("yourFolder", recursive = TRUE)
```

Comment: If you set `recursive` to `TRUE` in `list.files` you can list all files with the `pattern` in all subfolders of a folder.

Comment: @aosmith - thank you!  I've made an edit.  Totally forgot `list.files` had a recursive argument

Comment: @RichScriven I tried to extend your `sourceFolder` function to source the `cpp` files via the command `Rcpp::sourceCpp` but failed. Is it possible to extend your function to `cpp` files?